# Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, opensaml

I am newbie to the `WSO2 API Manager` version `1.9.1`. I wanted `x-jwt-assertion` to be decoded using the `OpenSAML` library (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml/2.6.4). I wanted same x-jwt-assertion (shown in this link [Decode X-JWT-Assertion using axiom-api in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498830/decode-x-jwt-assertion-using-axiom-api-in-java/34499026#34499026)) to be decoded/parse, but when Implement below code I see following errors coming. Please guide.

Is this possible to decode `x-jwt-assertion` of WSO2 APIM (API manager) using OpenSAML ?

The code for reference:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at com.mkyong.app.OpenSAMLDemo.main(OpenSAMLDemo.java:46)
```

The code for reference:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.opensaml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Assertion;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Response;
import org.opensaml.xml.ConfigurationException;
import org.opensaml.xml.XMLObject;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.Unmarshaller;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.UnmarshallerFactory;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.UnmarshallingException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class OpenSAMLDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
    ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, ConfigurationException, UnmarshallingException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(OpenSAMLDemo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jwtAssertion.properties"));

        String responseMessage = prop.getProperty("jwt");
        System.out.println(responseMessage);

        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        byte[] base64DecodedResponse = base64.decode(responseMessage);

        DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64DecodedResponse);

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);
        Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

        UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(element);
        XMLObject responseXmlObj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);

        Response response = (Response) responseXmlObj;

        Assertion assertion = response.getAssertions().get(0);

        String subject = assertion.getSubject().getNameID().getValue();
        System.out.println("SUBJECT  : " + subject );

        String issuer = assertion.getIssuer().getValue();
        System.out.println("ISSUER  : " + issuer);

        String audience = assertion.getConditions().getAudienceRestrictions().get(0).getAudiences().get(0).getAudienceURI();
        System.out.println("AUDIENCE  : " + audience );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for check can u try out decode using axiom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498830/decode-x-jwt-assertion-using-axiom-api-in-java

Comment: can you post the responseMessage you got (the message you are trying to decript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `WSO2 API Manager` tool. `API Manager` gives `X-JWT-Assertion` which is different from `WSO2 SAML Assertion`. so `OpenSAML` library won't works. Because it's not developed to support the `X-JWT-Assertion`. In order to parse the `X-JWT-Assertion`, you need to use the `axiom-api`.

Please refer this site and solution provided.
[Decode X-JWT-Assertion using axiom-api in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498830/decode-x-jwt-assertion-using-axiom-api-in-java)